# Change between> or <being by selecting select option

Tags: javascript

I want to make a comparison between the numbers of two inputs according to the choice I make in select option .
Can you help me how to do this?

```js
let in1 = document.getElementById("num1").value
let in2 = document.getElementById("num2").value
let con = document.getElementById("condition").value

function run() {
  if (in1 + con + in2) {
    var a = "yes"
  } else {
    var a = "no"
  }
  console.log(a)
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num1">
<select id="condition" name="condition" for="value">
  <option value=">"> ></option>
  <option value="<">
    <</option>
      <option value="==">= </option>
</select>
<input type="number" id="num2">
<br>
<button onclick="run()">compare</button>
```

Comment: Hint: You'll need to make use of `eval()`, and likely add sanitation to the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just concatenating strings, that doesn't evaluate them as expressions.

You can use the condition value is a key in an object that contains functions that test the appropriate conditions.

```js
function run() {
  let in1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
  let in2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
  let con = document.getElementById("condition").value

  const funcs = {
    '<': (x, y) => x < y,
    '>': (x, y) => x > y,
    '==': (x, y) => x == y
  };

  if (funcs[con](in1, in2)) {
    var a = "yes"
  } else {
    var a = "no"
  }
  console.log(a)
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num1">
<select id="condition" name="condition" for="value">
  <option value=">"> ></option>
  <option value="<">
    <</option>
      <option value="==">= </option>
</select>
<input type="number" id="num2">
<br>
<button onclick="run()">compare</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be a good idea to make use of an additional `if...else` statement to clearly define the operators.

```
let int1 = document.getElementById("num1").value
let int2 = document.getElementById("num2").value
let con = document.getElementById("condition").value


function run(int1, int2, con) {
  Number(int1);
  Number(int2);
  if (con === "<") {
    if (int1 < int2) {
      let a = "yes";
      return a;
    } else {
      let a = "no";
      return a;
    }
  } else if (con === ">") {
    if (int1 > int2) {
      let a = "yes";
      return a;
    } else {
      let a = "no";
      return a;
    }
  } else if (con === "==") {
    if (int1 === int2) {
      let a = "yes";
      return a;
    } else {
      let a = "no";
      return a;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What about `==`?

Comment: This would work the same here. My understanding is that `===` must be an exact equality for the condition to return true, whereas `==` is a a general equivalency. So `(10 == '10')` would return `true`, and `(10 === '10')` would return `false`. Would it be a better practice to use `==`?

Comment: You need to convert the inputs to numbers anyway. Otherwise `<` and `>` perform lexicographic comparisons, so `'2' > '12'`